# Return id of duplicate records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A short section of my database is as follows:

```
id   | name  |  age
-----+-------+------
   1 |  Ali  |  25
   2 |  Ali  |  25
   3 |  Fred |  45
   4 |  John |  13
   5 |  Fred |  45
```

**What I want:**

I want the `ids` of records that are the same.
In fact, I want to have the following expected output for example above.

```
id   | name  |  age
-----+-------+------
   1 |  Ali  |  25 <<---\
                        |-> [1, 2] -> |
   2 |  Ali  |  25 <<---/             | 
                                      |=> [1, 2, 3, 5] <- The ids must be return.
   3 |  Fred |  45 <<---\             |
   4 |  John |  13      |-> [3, 5] -> |
   5 |  Fred |  45 <<---/
```

I do many attempts and using of `groupBy` was the last attempt but not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get duplicate records you can use a correlated sub query using `esixts`

In SQL

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `age` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `name`, `age`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ali', 25),
    (2, 'Ali', 25),
    (3, 'Fred', 45),
    (4, 'John', 13),
    (5, 'Fred', 45)
;
```

Query

```
select a.*
from test a
where exists(
  select 1
  from test b 
  where a.name = b.name 
    and a.age = b.age
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Result

```
id  name    age
1   Ali     25
2   Ali     25
3   Fred    45
5   Fred    45
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e010a/5)

In query builder

```
$results = DB::table('test as a')
           ->whereExists(function ($query) {
               $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                     ->from('test as b')
                     ->whereRaw('a.name = b.name')
                     ->whereRaw('a.age = b.age')
                     ->havingRaw('count(*) > 1')
                     ;
           })
           ->get();
```

To get ids change `get()` to `get(['id'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple [havingRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) query:

```
$duplicates = DB::table('table_name')
    ->select('id', 'age', 'name', (DB::raw('COUNT(id)')))
    ->groupBy(['age', 'name'])
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > 1')
    ->pluck('id');
```

This will return you an array of user ID's, where the age and name are duplicate. *PS: Not tested, let me know if you have any problems.*